# C++: Calling overloaded virtual methods with parameters of the same base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

My question is related to C++. I have two families of classes: "Floor" and "Object". The first and the second family has a virtual method named "Enter" (which is called when an object enters the floor).

I wish to distinguish the behavior of "Enter" based on the sub-class of a "Floor" and "Object" respectively.

So I overload the method "Enter" with derived classes as the parameters. I have got code that works correctly, but requires two steps to call proper method, and would like to ask whether it can be done in one function call:

Edit: I updated the code (now full working example) with the potential solution. I have used a pointer to method with casting to retrieve proper overloaded method. This pointer is initialized in the constructors of the derived "Floor" classes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Floor;
class Flagstone;

class Object
{
public:
        virtual void Enter(Floor *f); /* Generic object enters generic floor */
        virtual void Enter(Flagstone *fs); /* Generic object enters flagstone */
};

class Box : public Object
{
public:
        void Enter(Floor *f);
        void Enter(Flagstone *fs);
};

class Floor
{
public:
        typedef void (Object::*enterPtr)(Floor *);

        enterPtr enter; /* Pointer to method, initialized by constructor */

        Floor(enterPtr enter) : enter(enter)
        {
        }
};

class Flagstone : public Floor
{
public:       
        /* Select proper overloaded function using casting */
        Flagstone() : Floor((enterPtr)(void (Object:: *)(Flagstone *))&Object::Enter)
        {
                 
        }
};


void Object::Enter(Floor *f)
{
        cout << " Generic object enters generic floor" << endl;
}

void Object::Enter(Flagstone *fs)
{
        cout << "Generic object enters flagstone" << endl;
}

void Box::Enter(Floor *f)
{
        /* Box enters generic floor */
        cout << "Box enters generic floor" << endl;
}

void Box::Enter(Flagstone *b)
{
        /* Executed when a Box enters Flagstone: Correct */
        cout << "Box enters Flagstone" << endl;
}

int main()
{
        Floor *f = new Flagstone();
        Object *o = new Box();

        (o->*(f->enter))(f);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to have a custom `Enter(Flagstone*)` is the base `Enter` forwards to `Floor::Enter`? What you want is not possible, the solution is to do what you already do: have a single `Object::Enter` that forward to `Box::Enter`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/5Y67KxjPY) after filling in some blanks in the code here. `o->Enter(f);` resolves to `Object::Enter(Floor*)` whose implementation is overriden by `Box::Enter(Floor*)`, which in turn invokes `Floor::Enter(Box*)` which is overridden by `Flagstone::Enter(Box*)` which is what's ultimately executed. That being said this behavior may not be what you're expecting in which case I agree with Holt: I don't understand why you think you need `Object::Enter(Flagstone*)` to begin with.

Comment: The Floor parameter is resolved as a Flagstone in the Box method only. If I use casting to Flagstone it works in one call.

Answer (score 0):

Could I ask you to provide a minimum, reproducible example? Copying the code as is doesn't compile; indeed, there seems to be a circular dependency between the Floor and Object classes, as both rely on each other's *implementation* to be defined at all!

Both me and Nathan have tried to resolve this by forward-declaring the derived subtype 'Box', but this might be moot because:

- you may want to invoke Box methods from Floor::Enter and Flagstone::Enter
- the compiler throws an error for 'an undefined reference to a vtable', with answers here:

I agree with the others that Object::Enter(Flagstone*) seems redundant seems redundant given there exists Object::Enter(Floor*), which can resolve the dynamic type of the pointer passed-in

Comment: I have updated the code with full working example. Found a potential solution - with pointer to overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just realizing that the `main()` in this code could be actually a virtual `Object` or `Floor` method! Proper method will be called at first place and it will know one of the objects' true class.

So I cleaned the code. The function `Enter(Floor *, Item *)` just calls `virtual` method `Floor::Enter()` and it delegates the control to `virtual` method `Item::Enter()`, but now with addition to overloading.

The result method just reacts for the specific `Floor` and `Item` for example: `Flagstone` and `Box` incrementing the placed boxes counter.

This is very clean solution, however I can't make the methods `inline` as there is a cycle dependancy. But it's not a problem.

Here is the solution code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Floor;
class Flagstone;

class Item
{
public:
    /* Overload */
    virtual void Enter(Floor *fl)
    {
        cout << "Item enters Floor." << endl;
    }
    virtual void Enter(Flagstone *fs)
    {
        cout << "Item enters Flagstone." << endl;
    }
};

class Box : public Item
{
public:
    static int count;

    virtual void Enter(Floor *fl)
    {
        cout << "Box enters Floor." << endl;
    }
    virtual void Enter(Flagstone *fs)
    {
        cout << "Box enters Flagstone. Count++" << endl;
        count++;
    }
};

class Cherry : public Item
{

};

class Item;

class Floor
{
public:
    /* Virtual Floor method. If object is in derived class, 
    it will call proper method. */
    virtual void Enter(Item *it);
};

class Flagstone : public Floor
{
public:
    virtual void Enter(Item *it);
};

class Wall : public Floor
{

};

/* Virtual Floor method. If object is in derived class, it will call proper method. */

void Floor::Enter(Item *it)
{
    /* OK, we have Floor and Item or Item sub-class now we call item method, enter */
    it->Enter(this);
}

void Flagstone::Enter(Item *it)
{
    /* OK, we have Flagstone */
    it->Enter(this);
}

int Box::count = 0;

void Enter(Floor *fl, Item *it)
{
    fl->Enter(it);
}

int main(void)
{
    Floor *fl = new Flagstone;
    Item *it = new Box;

    Enter(fl, it);
    return 0;
}
```